# 1D array in a ComboBox Qt C++

Tags: c++, arrays, qt, combobox

I have this function that reads data from text file and puts it in an array and also in a ComboBox. I need the array because I need it in a other function.

```
void MainWindow::Werknemers()
{
    int teller = 0;
    QFile inputFile("F://files//emails.txt");
    if (inputFile.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly))
    {
       QTextStream in(&inputFile);
       QString email[1000];
       while ( !in.atEnd() && teller < 1000)
       {
          QString line = in.readLine();
          email[teller++] = line;
          this->ui->ontvanger_input->addItem(line);
       }
     }
}
```

The file is succesfully opened (i checked) so I dont really know whats the problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `email` variable is declared inside the `MainWindow::Werknemers` scope and it's only visible there, being destroyed right after the scope ends. You should read a bit about [scope](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_variable_scope.htm) in C++.

At least that's what I guess the problem is, because you didn't say what's your error.

Comment: I don't get any errors, but I just get an empty comboBox. Even if I declare `email` outside `MainWindow::Werknemers()`.

Comment: @SvenWeerdenburg: how did you checked that your file is really successfully opened?

Comment: @Guid `if(!inputFile.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly)) {
    QMessageBox::information(0,"error",file.errorString());
}`

Comment: @SvenWeerdenburg how is `ontvanger_input` declared? The code looks fine. Try outputting the data to the console, so you're sure the lines are read properly.

Comment: @Guid used `qDebug() << line;` and it prints out just fine but it still doesnt add items to the comboBox

Comment: @Guid Oh wait is does print out 'something' to the Combobox but just blank items. Instead of nothing :P

Comment: @SvenWeerdenburg perhaps try doing `this->ui->ontvanger_input->addItem(email[teller-1]` since `email` should be global now? Instead of `this->ui->ontvanger_input->addItem(line);` of course.